# What does " hand-me-downs of talk" mean ?

Tags: idioms

for you to know the context, I am submitting a sentence.. 
" the collection of more modern hand-me-downs of talk can be found in.... " 
what is the meaning of "hand-me-downs of talk" ?

Answer (score 1):

A *[hand-me-down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hand-me-down)* is

> 1. a.  something, esp an outgrown garment, passed down from one person to another b.  (as modifier) a hand-me-down dress
> 2. a.  anything that has already been used by another b.  (as modifier) hand-me-down ideas

so a *hand-me-down of talk* would be a well-worn phrase that is not original to the speaker; particularly one that is trite, vacuous, or a [cliche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cliche).

Comment: thank You so much, it will be needed in tomorrow's class

Comment: I don't think the implication need be phrases that are trite or vacuous; "hand-me-downs of talk" can also be full of meaning and cultural significance.

Comment: @onomatomaniak; Are the two pairs opposed? "Two and two are four" is undoubtedly full of meaning and has considerable significance in Western culture.

Comment: @TimLymington I do think they are opposed, yes; *trite* connotes lacking import/significance (and I am saying they can be significant), while *vacuous* connotes lacking meaning (and I am saying they can be meaningful).